# Get CDSID from JWT?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt

I am wondering if there is any way to be able to fetch the CDSID from a JWT?
I can get this information, as of now:

[image]

So this question is kind of related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/c/volvocargroup/questions/119), might be able to add the CDSID to the JWT in the app manifest in some way? Otherwise I could just split on @ but that doesn't feel to safe :P

Answer (score 0):

Looking a bit more in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/c/volvocargroup/questions/119), the "upn" value actually is the user principle name. So I guess the solution could look like this:

```
var cdsId = user.Identity.Name.Split('@')[0]
```